# How to find the pixel location in original image in ios

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitouch

I have an image with size `480x360` and am displaying in `UIImageview` with frame `(0, 0, 320, 568)` with `aspectfill`.

When I touch the image view, location says `(150,120)`. How can I map this location in my original image `(480x360)` format?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You just calculate the proportions and apply them to touch location point.

```
CGFloat _x = imageView.image.size.width / imageView.frame.size.width;
CGFloat _y = imageView.image.size.height / imageView.frame.size.height;

//assuming p - is CGPoint received from Touch event
CGPoint locationInImageView = CGPointMake(p.x * _x, p.y * _y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the pixel location of the touch in Swift:

```
guard let image = imageView.image else {
    return
}

let x = image.size.width / imageView.frame.size.width
let y = image.size.height / imageView.frame.size.height

// Assuming touchLocation is CGPoint received from Touch event
var touchLocation: CGPoint
let locationInImageView = CGPoint(x: touchLocation.x * x, y: touchLocation.y * y);
```