# How to get position(or coordinates) of particular pixel in a UIImage on touch

Tags: swift, uiimage, image-rendering

On touching on the image I want to get coordinate of that pixel, I tried some code but not getting exact location where the user touches on the image.

This my existing code

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: self)


        let Z1 = self.image!.size.height

        let Z2 = self.image!.size.width

        let Z3 = self.bounds.minY

        let Z4 = self.bounds.minX

        let Z5 = self.bounds.height

        let Z6 = self.bounds.width

        let pos1 = (position.x - Z4) * Z2 / Z6

        let pos2 = (position.y - Z3) * Z1 / Z5

        let point = CGPoint(x: pos1, y: pos2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: let Z1 = ImageView.image!.size.height
            
            let Z2 = ImageView.image!.size.width
            
            let Z3 = ImageView.bounds.minY
            
            let Z4 = ImageView.bounds.minX
            
            let Z5 = ImageView.bounds.height
            
            let Z6 = ImageView.bounds.width
            
            let pos1 = (position.x - Z4) * Z2 / Z6
            
            let pos2 = (position.y - Z3) * Z1 / Z5
            
            let point = CGPoint(x: pos1, y: pos2)

i have tried with this code

Comment: You should [edit] your question with that code. Also, it doesn't seem like you are getting any user input from anywhere. Are you doing this in a `touchesBegan` method or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Is your touchesBegan getting called ? If so this should be enough..

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let pos = touch.location(in: imageView)
            print(pos.x)
            print(pos.y)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in touchesBegan if it is getting called please

Comment: yes its and also giving me position, but position is working

Comment: i need exact pixel location

Comment: try looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331852/how-to-find-the-pixel-location-in-original-image-in-ios)